# Using Physics.Raycast inside OnCollisionEnter2D function

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, physics

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
       foreach(ContactPoint2D contact in collision.contacts) 
       {
           RaycastHit raycastInfo;
           Physics.Raycast(contact.point, Vector3.forward, out raycastInfo, 1000.0f);
           if(raycastInfo.collider)
           {
               Debug.Log("Hit!");
           }
       }
    }
```

I am using this code to raycast an abject with the contact position of collision. The collision part works fine, when collision happens this function is triggered. But when I raycast to that position, RaycastHit variable return empty.

I couldn't find what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're mixing 3D & 2D physics.

You're using [OnCollisionEnter**2D**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html), which triggers when 2D colliders hit each other.

But then you're using [Physics.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html), which casts rays against 3D colliders - so it won't be able to detect the two colliders that triggered the event, or any similar colliders in your scene. Maybe you want [Physics**2D**.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)?

Comment: Thanks, my bad. I didn't think that would cause a problem. Solved it.